# LLVM: What changes need to be made in makefile to use llvm-link

Tags: makefile, llvm

I have source code of a project. I can create Makefile by running the command ./configure.
Now if I want to change the compiler from gcc to clang, I can do this by 
CC=clang ./configure.
Similarly if I want to use llvm-link as a linker, is there anything similar to this ? 
Otherwise what changes should I do in the makefile?

Comment: Have you tried redefining `LD`?

Comment: Yes..tried 'LD=llvm-ld'

Comment: Often the C or C++  compiler (CC or CXX) is used in the link command line. In this case you may have to convince clang via the LDFLAGS to link bitcode. You will likely also need -emit-llvm in the CFLAGS and likely also the LDFLAGS

Comment: Did you try `LD = llvm-link` ? Or was that a typo in your comment?

Comment: @FrankC. There was no typo in my comment. Actually llvm-link would link all the llvm bitcode files together. If I am not wrong, here we are trying to link the .o files, which is performed by the llvm-ld. Then also, I have tried with LD=llvm-link

Comment: Well, it depends on the Makefile. Is the configure script or the Makefile something you can share? Do you know if configure is created by autoconf? If so you may be able to create a complete and minimal example that people can try out and have a look at. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The output of configure and make may also point us in the right direction.

Comment: @PaulR. I don't think so I would be able to create any minimal example. The exact project I am targeting on is binutils 2.26 https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.26.tar.gz .You can find the configure file there.

Comment: I think echristo's Answer is correct for binutils (and with every "standard" makefile). Binutils uses libtool and $(CC) ... $(LDFLAGS) to link. One thing I have probably misunderstood: do you just want to set the linker for ordinary .o files or do you want to generate LLVM bitcode and then link that? Note that in the question you wrote llvm-link, that's why I thought you wanted to link bitcode to bitcode.

Comment: @PaulR But I am not able to use -fuse-ld=lld. I think I am making some mistake in my command. Can you give me command how to do it?

Comment: did you try "LDFLAGS='-fuse-ld=lld' configure"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`llvm-link` is a bitcode linker and not a full linker. For that you want lld. At that point you can pass `-fuse-ld=lld` to pick up lld as your linker in your link step. You can use LDFLAGS for this.

See [lld's documentation](https://lld.llvm.org/) for more information.